# Subset of table that has unique value for a specific column in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL. I have a table of 5000 records with 44 columns. I need to have a subset of this table that contains 10 of the columns and all of the rows that have unique value for a specific column (`NationalCode`).

In other words this subset should present all the unique people and ignore the rows that have a repeated `NationalCode`.

I know that the query below is wrong but what is the correct form?

```
insert into Patient(NationalID, P_FirstName, P_LastName, P_FatherName, Gender, P_Age, P_AgeGroup, P_MaritalStatus)
    select  
        P_NationalCode, P_FirstName, P_LastName, 
        P_FatherName, FullDateAlternateKey, P_Age, P_AgeGroup, 
        P_MaritalStatus
    from 
        OriginalData 
    where 
        P_NationalCode in (select distinct P_NationalCode
                           from OriginalData)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `WHERE` ...

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql server 2012

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
insert into Patient(NationalID, P_FirstName, P_LastName, P_FatherName, Gender, P_Age, P_AgeGroup, P_MaritalStatus)
select  
    P_NationalCode, P_FirstName, P_LastName, 
    P_FatherName, FullDateAlternateKey, P_Age, P_AgeGroup, 
    P_MaritalStatus
from 
    (select P_NationalCode, P_FirstName, P_LastName, 
    P_FatherName, FullDateAlternateKey, P_Age, P_AgeGroup, 
    P_MaritalStatus ,row_number() over(partition by P_NationalCode  order by P_NationalCode) as rowNumber from OriginalData
   ) data
where 
   rowNumber=1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works well. Would you please tell me how it work?

Comment: I mean about Row_number().

Comment: I used row_number to get the data ordered for every national code using “partition by” then get get the first row from every nationalCode using where rownumber=1, —check this link  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql